# python not able to find the certificate file path

Tags: python, filepath, os.path

My program structure is of the form:

```
    -worker
         -worker
              --lib
                  ----file.py
                  ----cert.pem
         -app.py
```

Inside file.py I have following code:

```py
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filepath = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cert.pem')
```

When I run the service which is through app.py, it fails at file.py line L2 stating:

```
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/worker/lib/../lib/cert.pem
```

Could someone have any idea why python is taking "lib" directory twice and putting ".." in between?

Comment: Try `BASE_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS posted by @Selcuk: This worked for me.:

```
     BASE_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) – Selcuk
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is usually best to handle paths.

```py
import pathlib

BASE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
filepath = BASE_DIR / "cert.pem"

print(filepath)
# >>> /Users/felipe/Desktop/example_project/cert.pem
```

Note the `example.py` (above) is also inside `example_project` folder.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve it. It still showed the exact same error message -  " OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/worker/lib/../lib/cert.pem "